# How can I display the latest value in Chart?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, charts

I have to display chart that is connected with db dynamically. It is working fine. The code is given below. But my issue is my db is automatically update in every 5 minutes. So I have to display the chart with latest inserted information. Please help me.
The code is given below:

```
public partial class chartDummy : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"ConnectionString");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Mains_Run_Hrs, DG_Run_Auto_Mode, Battery_Run_Hrs, Solar_Run_hrs from tbl_runtime_report", con);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataView source = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
            Chart1.DataSource = ds;
            Chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Mains_Run_Hrs";
            Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "DG_Run_Auto_Mode";
            Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Battery_Run_Hrs";
            Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Solar_Run_hrs";
            Chart1.DataBind();

    }   
}
```

Comment: window.location.reload(); in JavaScript

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">

Comment: @Thirisangu : Thank you. Do you konw any sql query for this operation.

Comment: Here SQL query is no need, The existing query automatically fetches the recent record from DB on every five minutes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Mains_Run_Hrs, DG_Run_Auto_Mode, Battery_Run_Hrs, Solar_Run_hrs from tbl_runtime_report ORDER BY Site_ID DESC", con);
```